# SQL - get start & end balance for each member each year

Tags: sql, db2

so I'd like to effectively get for each year the starting and end balance for each member for every year there is a record. for example the below would give me the latest balance for each member each year based on the date column

```
SELECT 
        T.MemberID,
        T.DateCol,
        T.Amount
FROM
        (SELECT T.MemberID,
        T.DateCol,
        Amount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID,
    YEAR(DateCol)
ORDER BY
    DateCol desc) AS seqnum
FROM
    Tablet T
GROUP BY DateCol, MemberID, Amount
     ) T
WHERE
    seqnum = 1 AND
    MemberID = '1000009'
```

and the below would give me the earliest balance for each year

```
SELECT 
        T.MemberID,
        T.DateCol,
        T.Amount
FROM
        (SELECT T.MemberID,
        T.DateCol,
        Amount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID,
    YEAR(DateCol)
ORDER BY
    DateCol) AS seqnum
FROM
    Tablet T
GROUP BY DateCol, MemberID, Amount
     ) T
WHERE
    seqnum = 1 AND
    MemberID = '1000009'
```

This would give me a result set like the below, column titles (MemberID, Date, Amount)

[image]

What I'm looking for is one query which is done by YEAR, MEMBERID, STARTBALANCE, ENDBALANCE as the columns. And would look like the below

[image]

What would be the best way to go about this?

commented above

Comment: Look up the *first_value* window function.

Comment: Is [that](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hx5VJDps) what you need?